# My chat profile won't update

Tags: bug, profile-page, chat

[My chat profile](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/5768335/dsafds) won't synchronize with [my Stack Overflow account](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5768335/amanuel2).  I have changed my display name to *amanuel2* but the chat profile is still stuck with the old placeholder name.

I have been experiencing this for weeks, and also with [Ultron](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/6855339/ultron), my bot account (the avatar won't change).

In the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers), I [reached](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/33129247#33129247) moderator [Madara Uchiha](https://stackoverflow.com/users/871050/madara-uchiha), who then tried to forcefully change my profile, but it seemed to have failed.  According to him, this appears to be a bug.

Is there anything I can do, and failing that, could a site admin please step in and see what's up with this?

You can see that my name didn't update from Dsafds to amanuel2:

[image]
[image]

Comment: I've seen this happen a few times when a chat account was created based on a main site account, the main site account was deleted for being a sock puppet, and then a new account was recreated using the same credentials as the previously deleted puppet. Looking at the history, I'm betting that's the case here, because you've had several accounts deleted.

Comment: @BradLarson Yea i switched accounts I'm pretty sure ... Is there a way to fix this , or just hope StackOverflow Finds a big to this issue?

Comment: "the main site account was deleted...and then a new account was recreated using the same credentials" Possible (cross-site) duplicate of [Can't enter the Tavern on the Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281378/cant-enter-the-tavern-on-the-meta)